# Comparing a string to hexa string

Tags: c, string

I have a Hexadecimal string `hexa="ffffffff 0 0";` and an other string entered by the user from the console for example `String="ffffffff 0 0";`, i want to compare hexa to String in this case i want to have hexa equal String.
How can i do that,i'm working with C language i have searched around but i can't find an answer and i tried strcmp obviously did not work, I also tried `sprintf(String2,"%s",hexa);` then `strcmp(String2,String) ;`did not work either.

Comment: Why did `strcmp` 'obviously not work'?

Comment: I don't believe you've posted your actual code. If you did post your actual code then it doesn't work because you're copying `hexa` to `String2` and then comparing `String2` to `String` rather than `hexa`. So either fix that error or show us your actual code. To help you we need to see the actual code you're using, not pseudocode.

Comment: Yes, show us some compilable code that demonstrates your problem. Show us how you are getting input from the console, since some methods might append the closing `newline` to an input string.

Answer (score 2):

You most likely misinterpreted how `strcmp` works. It returns an integer which indicates the relationship between the strings. If you want to check whether they are equal, you should check if `strcmp` returned zero, like so:

```
if(strcmp(String,String2) == 0){
    // Strings are equal
} else {
    // Strings are not equal
}
```

Comment: i know how strcmp work and if i compare hexa to String or hexa to String2 i don't have 0 i have 1 or -1 ;so is there any way to compare

Comment: That means that the strings are not equal, `strcmp` did it's job correctly. What do you mean with 'hexadecimal string' anyway? Is it a hexadecimal representation of some data? What are you comparing it with? Please add some details to your question and I might be able to help you.

Comment: i'm rading data from the hard disque and i stock the contenent of a specific sector in hexa ,the user enter a string i need to search for this string in hexa

Comment: @sarahklif Look, `strcmp` works. Period. So either you're doing something wrong or your definition of "did not work" is wrong. Without seeing your code we can't tell you which it is.

Comment: ok i will ask my question diffrently, for example i have this `printf("the string you want to search for ");
fgets(str2, 65, stdin);
printf("\n init = %s",str2);
printf("\n init = %x",str2);
printf("\n hexa  = %x",str2[0]);
printf("\n hexa  = %x",str2[1]);i want to have if i print str2 in  hexa with %x i would have the same thing as if i print with  %s`

Comment: @sarahklif If you want to revise your question you need to edit it. Posting code as a comment is unreadable and not what comments are for.